# Apply transition only for foreground text color. Not for the background image

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to use the css3 transition only for the text color?

Suppose I have a `readmore` class which has some transition effect like

```css
.readmore{
    colour:red;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
    background:url(images/sprite.png) no-repeat 0 0;

}



.readmore:hover{
    colour:red;
    background:url(images/sprite.png) no-repeat 0 -20px;
}
```

Now I don't want to apply the background image transition. I need to apply the transition only for color. Because when we mouse over on the text the image is animating and it doesn't looks good.

Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reference for @DmitryDvornikov 's answer: [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-property).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of specifying that you want to transition `all` properties you can specify that you only want to transition the `color` property.

Like this:

```
transition: color .3s ease-out;
```

And change `colour` to `color`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use this option:

```
transition-property:color;
```